# Hide Wordpress "wp-admin" dashboard to User IDS

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to remove & redirect any users of a site from accessing

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/
```

Unless there id is one,
i have seen some examples floating around the ask if admin-ajax is being used if so redirect. how ever this is not approach i wish to make as im using admin ajax on the front end for some admins. i just don't wish them to see anything to do with the backend of wordpress.

Only userid 1 should have access to wp-admin.

Comment: While this is a fair question for stackoverflow, you *may* get a better answer at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com They are probably better prepared to answer questions by suggesting plugins and config options as opposed to just code.

Comment: My thought here though would be to add a custom role [something like this](https://wedevs.com/98266/add-custom-user-roles-wordpress/) and then add some code to prevent that role from accessing wp-admin [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66093/how-to-prevent-access-to-wp-admin-for-certain-user-roles). Then you can just slot users into that role and let the magic happen.

Comment: Thanks i might ask over there.
And yeh originally i thought that would be the way to go.

Because the method i have in place isn't exactly ideal
I have a custom javascript that is hooked on wp-admin load
`if(userSettings.uid !== "1"){
// code to hide and redirect here.
}`

Comment: I agree. And javascript can be so easily manipulated by the user, that they can still just waltz right into your admin panel if they want to. I think server side role based permissions checking is definitely the cleaner and safer way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WP-Cerber will serve your needs? https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cerber/

Checkout the part:
"You can hide WordPress dashboard (/wp-admin/) when a user isn’t logged in. If a user isn’t logged in and they attempt to access the dashboard by requesting /wp-admin/, WP Cerber will return a 404 Error."

It also has the option to create a custom url for /wp-login.php (usually an address that is targeted by bots).

If you want to do it without a plugin you can use htaccess RewriteRule: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/how-to-redirect-rewrite-all-wp-login-requests